# python 3 data validation assignment error

Tags: python-3.x

so i have this data validation program which validated the name, email and age but its giving me an error

```
def emailcheck():
  if (email[0] == "@"):
    print("email not valid try again")
    email = input("enter email:")
  if ("@" not in email):
    print("your email is not valid")
    email = input("enter email:")
  if (email == ""):
    print("email is empty")
    email = input("enter email:")

def namecheck():
  if (name == ""):
    print("name is empty")
    name = input("enter name:")           

def agecheck():
  if (age != int):
    print("age must be a number")
    age = input("enter your age:")
  if (age != range(1,120)):
    print("i dont even know what to say")
    age = input("enter your age:")          

while True:
    email = input("enter email:")

    emailcheck()
    name = input("enter name:")

    namecheck()
    age = input("enter your age:")

    agecheck()
```

heres the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 29, in 
  File "python", line 2, in emailcheck
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'email' referenced before assignment

i need this solved please

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variables as parameters in your functions because they will not be defined in that scope. e.g.
`def emailcheck(email):`